# Xamarin.Forms UWP - Setting WebView.Source as HtmlWebViewSource Processes Scripts Twice

Tags: xamarin, webview, xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.uwp

In Xamarin.Forms UWP, if I have a `WebView` whose `Source` property is set to type `UrlWebViewSource`, it works as expected. BUT, if the `Source` property is set to type `HtmlWebViewSource` where the `Html` property is set as a string, then any `<script>`s in the HTML are processed **twice**.

I've set up a brand new Xamarin.Forms project, where the `Content` of the MainPage is set to a WebView in the code-behind. I've set it up so that I can easily switch out between setting the `WebView.Source` to `UrlWebViewSource` or `HtmlWebViewSource`:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var urlSource = new UrlWebViewSource { Url = "https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/joelbyrd/external-resources/blob/master/storefulfillment/Printing/Packing/GNC-Pick.htm" };
    var htmlStringSource = new HtmlWebViewSource
    {
        Html = @"<!doctype html><html lang='en'><head><meta charset='utf-8'><meta http-equiv='x-ua-compatible' content='ie=edge'><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'><title>Test</title></head><body><div id='log'></div><p>some text</p><script>document.getElementById('log').innerHTML += `<p>Testing</p>`;</script></body></html>"
    };

    var webView = new WebView
    {
        Margin = new Thickness(0, 20, 0, 0),
        Source = urlSource, // displays as expected
        //Source = htmlStringSource // <script>'s are processed twice, appending "Testing" to the body twice
    };

    Content = webView;
}
```

It's a problem that the scripts are executed twice, probably for several reasons, but for one, if I'm appending content to the body with JavaScript, then it will be appended twice - **not** what I want. Here's the test HTML code I'm using:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="log"></div>
    <p>some text</p>

    <script>
        document.getElementById('log').innerHTML += `<p>Testing</p>`;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I set the `WebView.Source` to type `UrlWebViewSource`, and set the `Url` property to "https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/joelbyrd/external-resources/blob/master/storefulfillment/Printing/Packing/GNC-Pick.htm", I get the following expected output:

[image]

**BUT** When I set the `WebView.Source` to type `HtmlWebViewSource`, with the `Html` property set to the string above (spaces taken out and properly escaped), I get the following:

[image]

You can see that "Testing" has been added to the body twice. This **only happens in UWP**, so I suspect it's a bug. Can anyone tell me what's going on here, and if there's a workaround?

Comment: I have reproduced the issue, it may be a bug. And I found this code [segment](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP/WebViewRenderer.cs#L43). And this code will cause endless loop.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT - I actually had already reported it already [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/2631). Feel free to close whichever you think would be best.